# Parts of the Ubuntu 18.04 GUI (nautilus, editor) not updating

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, gui

This is my first topic here so please excuse me if I'm not sticking to the rules 100%.

My current problem is, that I cannot browse through different files or write in my Editor. I don't get any error messages.

Whenever I open nautilus (files), the window pops up correctly, but when I want to browse to a subfolder, the gui is not refreshing even though I get this little loading circle on the cursor. Ctrl+R also does not update the gui correctly. I can open .txt files by doubleclicking them if I know where they are, so the application is not completely crashed. Merely the window is not refreshing correctly.

The same happens when I open the editor, I can open it and type stuff, but I don't see what is written. Browsing through the folders via the terminal works without any issue.

I already tried

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus  
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell
```

based on [this](https://superuser.com/a/1382734) answer but it did not solve the problem.

I also killed all nautilus processes manually without solving the issue. Because it is not only affecting nautilus I expect the error to be somewhere else, but I honestly have no idea where to look at. Since it is a headless machine used for research purposes I can't just restart the server, or better said I don't want to stop the codes of our students if there might be a different fix.

A GTX 1050 is installed with the driver 440.48.02.

Has anybody else experienced this behavior and/or found a solution?

Comment: I tried switching to lightdm without any improvements (if that is what you meant with desktop environment). Restarting the server fixed it (for now), but now many simulations are interrupted and have to be repeated. I still have no idea what caused the issues.

Comment: Desktop environments: ubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-desktop, xubuntu-desktop and so on.